# With Hugo, can we use HTML code in a md file?

Tags: hugo

With Hugo, I am writing some HTML as Goldmark markdown doesn't support CSS classes or IDs.

My code is in post1.md:

```html
<h2 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-definition" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-definition">Définition</h2>
```

The above is not compiled to HTML.
Even the simplest `div` markup is omitted.

Comment: You can add HTML attributes but only to headings: `## heading {#id .className attrName=attrValue class="class1 class2"}`

Comment: You can add CSS classes to blocks like: Some paragraph (next line) {.my-css-class}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From version 0.6, Hugo uses Goldmark for markdown.

For security reasons, Goldmark wipes HTML code.

However, if you use HTML frequently in your site, you can add to your `config.toml`

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
  unsafe = true # Allow HTML in md files
```

For a less frequent usage of HTML, you can add `safeHTML` parameter to your HTML string ([Hugo doc for safeHTML](https://gohugo.io/functions/safehtml/)).